# Can I prevent the user of my program to resize the console window? (in C)

Tags: c, windows, console, resize, window

So I was searching (a lot) and haven't find anything on how to prevent user from resizing my program's console window. I had found information for language `C++` and `C#` but not for `C`. I already managed to set the size of the console but if the user changes it afterwards it is not good for my program's looking. Is there anything I can do to perfectly resize the console and keep it that way?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows, yeah thank you for asking I forgot to put it there.

Comment: Many of the Windows API functions can be called from C even when the MS documentation tags C++.

Comment: well you could include windows.h header file in your program and then look for a function that would make your program window size fixed.

Comment: Take look at the following http://zetcode.com/gui/winapi/ it will teach you how use windows api with C.

Comment: Yeah I have seen that one, maybe I give it some time and read the whole thing later on.

Comment: For c++ developers there is this cool framework know as Qt which uses windows api by default and you can create beautiful apps with it. Try it sometimes.

Comment: @zett42 undefined reference to 'GetConsoleWindow' - it is a C++ solution.

Comment: `GetConsoleWindow` is a C function. As stated in the reference, define `_WIN32_WINNT` as 0x0500 or later and include "Windows.h".

Comment: Then why is my compiler says 'undefined reference'? I already included windows.h.

Comment: define _WIN32_WINNT as 0x0500 or later

Comment: Your edit is not required and just adds noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trap the [EVENT_CONSOLE_LAYOUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-winevents) event by setting an event hook with [SetWinEventHook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd373640), and in the [WinEventProc callback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373885%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) call [SetConsoleWindowInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolewindowinfo) to immediately restore the desired size.

You might also set the window buffer to the exact dimensions of the visible window using [SetWindowScreenBufferSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolescreenbuffersize) since it is not possible to make the visible window larger than the buffer size.  This will not prevent making the windows smaller however.

Answer (score 12):

Okay so I managed to do the magic with combining codes.
First of all you need a

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500
```

and after that (*the order is important*)

```
#include <windows.h>
```

and after all this you need this code in your main:

```
HWND consoleWindow = GetConsoleWindow();
SetWindowLong(consoleWindow, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(consoleWindow, GWL_STYLE) & ~WS_MAXIMIZEBOX & ~WS_SIZEBOX);
```

Comment: Much better than my suggestion!  I'll let my answer stand however since there are other useful things that can be done with console WinEvents.