# Print text to the middle of the screen

Tags: c++, c, windows, console, centering

I am asking if there is any way, and how to print text like the Windows installation "**We're setting things up for you**" to the middle of the screen? If I can, can I make it so only the text gets displayed and the text background should be your desktop.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29091028/windows-api-write-to-screen-as-on-screen-display

Comment: `the text background should be your desktop` what does this mean? You want to print the desktop image into console as text?

Comment: @phuclv That means only the text should be displayed, no console, nothing, Only a big text in the middle of the screen

Comment: If one of the answers was helpful then mark it as accepted. If you have a different solution then post (and accept) your own answer. Don't change the question title to "(SOLVED)". That helps nobody who reads your question in the future.

Comment: you [accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking the green check mark on it. Editing the question isn't the way this site works. Please take 1 minute reading the [tour] to know how it works

Answer (score 0):

The classic way to deal with the console in Windows is via the [Console API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions). To get the console size you can use [`GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolescreenbufferinfo?redirectedfrom=MSDN). Here's a very simple example that draws a string at the center of the screen

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdint>
#include <windows.h>

int main(void)
{
    auto stdout_handle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    std::string str;

    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO oldcsbi{};
    COORD coord{};
    while (1)
    {
        CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
        GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(stdout_handle, &csbi);
        if (csbi.srWindow.Bottom != oldcsbi.srWindow.Bottom || csbi.srWindow.Right != oldcsbi.srWindow.Right)
        {
            std::fill(str.begin(), str.end(), ' ');
            SetConsoleCursorPosition(stdout_handle, coord);
            std::cout << str; // clear the old text
            
            oldcsbi = csbi;
            std::ostringstream s;

            s << "Console size: " << csbi.srWindow.Right << 'x' << csbi.srWindow.Bottom;
            str = s.str();
            coord.X = (short)((csbi.srWindow.Right - str.size()) / 2);
            coord.Y = (short)(csbi.srWindow.Bottom/2);
            SetConsoleCursorPosition(stdout_handle, coord);
            std::cout << str; // draw the new text
        }
        Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

[image: console resize example]

The above code gets the console size periodically and redraws the screen if the size has been changed. It loops indefinitely until you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or close the program

For more information about the Console API see [Using the Console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/using-the-console)

---

But of course [polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science)) the size like that isn't very good because it makes the output not very smooth and also eats up CPU cycles. The real solution is to **listen to the resize events** and do the necessary things in that callback function

There's a mode called [`ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/low-level-console-modes) which passes the resize events to the console where you can read by the blocking [`ReadConsoleInput()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleinput) or [`PeekConsoleInput()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/peekconsoleinput) APIs. You can see an example in [Reading Input Buffer Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/reading-input-buffer-events). Just run it and resize the window, the resize events will be printed out

Unfortunately in that mode only the [*console buffer size change* event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-input-buffer) is fired through the [`WINDOW_BUFFER_SIZE_RECORD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/input-record-str) and there's no *console screen size change* event, so if you change the number of rows then most of the time no events are generated. That means you'll need to go to a lower level and listen to the [Console Winevent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-winevents) named `EVENT_CONSOLE_LAYOUT`:

```
HWINEVENTHOOK eventHook = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_CONSOLE_LAYOUT, EVENT_CONSOLE_LAYOUT,
                                        NULL, EventProc, 0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT);
...
MSG msg;
while (GetMessage(&msg, g_hWindow, EVENT_CONSOLE_LAYOUT, EVENT_CONSOLE_LAYOUT)) {
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
```

You can find more details in

- [How do I disable or detect mode changes in Windows Console?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60983871/995714)
- [Can I prevent the user of my program to resize the console window? (in C)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47358043/995714)

---

The easier and even better way is to use [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) and handle something similar to [`SIGWINCH`](https://forums.justlinux.com/showthread.php?137431-ncurses-detect-when-the-terminal-has-been-resized). There were many Windows ports for ncurses in the past, and given Windows 10 console [supports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences) [ANSI sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) it's even easier to write an ncurses port. In fact nowadays it's [recommended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/classic-vs-vt) to [use ANSI sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/ecosystem-roadmap) for terminal interaction instead of the ole Console API for portability

- [Is ncurses available for windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/138153/995714)
- [NCurses-Like System for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2713698/995714)
- [Any Windows Substitutes For Curses/NCurses?](https://www.reddit.com/r/roguelikedev/comments/4gwriv/any_windows_substitutes_for_cursesncurses/)
- [Ncurses for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/ncurses.htm)

Answer (score -1):

```
<Window x:Class="YourApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="800" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent"  Topmost="True">
    
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Your Text Here"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Please note that this will work only until some other application declares itself TopMost.
Suggestion by [Window “on desktop”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/365171/7514472)

Comment: Thank you but I want to do it in c/c++ not in c# WPF.

Comment: Sorry, there is no language C/C++, so you won't be able to do this.  You may be able to do this in the C language **OR** C++.

Comment: Thomas, i was saying i want to do this in C or C++ language, the '/' means "or", so C or C++ language